# The type initializer for 'Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseConnection' threw an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, sybase

I created ASP.Net web application in Visual Studio 2019.
This application uses Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll to connect to Sybase database.

InnerException = "Could not load C:\Users\....\AppData\Local\Temp\Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.32bits.2.157.1410.0\sybcsi_openssl210.dll"

the project target framework is .Net Framework 4.5

How do fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try to find out how to include required libraries in your project?

Comment: Yes,I already add the libraries in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i use the old version 2.157.1000.0 to Fix this problem.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install nuget package -> `AdoNetCore.AseClient`.

Then, please use `using AdoNetCore.AseClient;` in the top of code.

Finally, you can use the following code without any exception.

```
 AseConnection connection = new AseConnection();
```

Besides, we need to note that we have to use .net core app because the limit of AdoNetCore.Aseclient.

Comment: Can't use AdoNetCore.AseClient because the project target framework is .NET Framework 4.5 not .Net Core.

Comment: @YanhaoChen, I forget to tell you that AdoNetCore.AseClient only can be used for .net core app. Therefore, I suggest that you can try .net core console app or asp.net core app.

Comment: Thanks, if the issue can't fix, i will try.